# Indexing a PDF document and providing additional JSON data using Solr Cell

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr-cell

I'm using Solr Cell to index PDF documents in my Solr collection. I also have additional metadata in JSON format that I want to associate with each indexed PDF document. Is it possible to index both the PDF document and the JSON data in a single request to Solr?

```
<field name="author" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
<field name="source" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
<field name="content" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

The content field needs to be filled with data extracted from the PDF, while the author and source fields should be populated with data provided in the JSON document.

Could you please provide an example of how I can send a request to Solr, including both the PDF document in binary and the JSON data, to achieve this?

Comment: Submit your document as normal to `/solr/<collection>/update/extract`, provide the literal values as query string arguments: `/update/extract?literal.author=Author&literal.source=MySource`

Comment: Works great! So it is impossible to provide metada in form as JSON like in normal 'update' request, but it isn't really necessary if I can pass them like this

Comment: Yes, since the body of the request is the file to be indexed, there isn't really anywhere you can stick that JSON.